# Is there any way to force a system to launch an app from a pendrive?

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive, autorun

I need to write an app that will be launched after plugging in a pendrive without the user interference. 
(The app will be on the pen drive.) 
I know that Windows blocks the autorun.inf execution because of the security (I can't even add a position to the AutoPlay (?) menu, which would be enough for me). I have been reading that, in case of CDs, autorun.inf is launched, and pendrives with U3 system can emulate CDs, but I don't know what drive will be used. (In detail – I write a program that, after doing some operations on drive, is to be launched after plugging or even clicking a position in that dumb menu. And no, it's not related with viruses, data deletion or something like that.) I thought, that maybe there is any way to fit some little program or something in the NTFS, and force system to run it, but as I researched for the NTFS file system I found out that it's probably impossible.

I am looking for a solution that works on all computers
(i.e., not requiring a specific configuration)
running any version of Windows. 
I am not as concerned about versions earlier than Windows Vista,
as those versions support `autorun.inf`.

Comment: Are you trying to auto-launch a program on the pendrive, or the program is on the computer and the pendrive is just the trigger?  Is this supposed to work on any computer or a specific one?

Comment: If you’re specifically interested on one particular version of Windows, please say so. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. AutoRun was the only method of instructing a Windows computer to load software when any type of digital media was inserted, and correctly, due to very real security concerns, this was modified and disabled. The OS will read the disc and offer the user some options for viewing the content safely.

If there was a work around, you that virus and malware makers would be the first people to make use of that, so there is no workaround.

If you are on a managed domain you could write a task or script that checked for certain criteria and then ran a file, and because it was initiated by a trusted part of the system (the Task Scheduler, for instance) that should work. But without a method of getting such a policy and configuration to the computers, you are out of luck.